# Alert is not working in pop up window in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

Could any one help me,to find out my problem.I have set my website as chrome extension.When I install the extension,it navigates to a popup window asking user name and password along with a login button. But when I tried to alert the username entered by the user in javascript,it is not working.Anyone please help me.What would be the reason?
Here is my manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Calpine Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Log on to calpinemate",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
},
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension",
    "default_icon": "calpine_not_logged_in.png"
},
"permissions": [

  "*://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php",
  "alarms",
 "notifications"
  ],
   "web_accessible_resources": [
   "/icon_128.png"]

 }
```

Here is my code that creates a pop up window on installation

```
      chrome.windows.create({url : "test.html"});
```

here is my test.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function log(){
            var uname=document.getElementById('name');
           alert(uname);
            }
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form name="userinfo" id="userinfo">
    username : 
    <input id="name" type="text" name="username"/><br><br>
    password :
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Log In" onclick="log()"/>
    <p id="pp"></p>
      </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it is not working is that `test.html` is opened as a "view" of your extension and the **[Content Security Policy (CSP)](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution)** prevents inline scripts and inline event-binding from being executed.

You should move the code and the event-bindings to an external JS file.

**In *test.html*:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <input type="button" id="login" value="Log In" />
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

**In *test.js*:**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var login = document.querySelector('input#login');

    login.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // ...do stuff...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick up value of the input field:

```
var uname = document.getElementById('name').value;
```

Comment: Hi Anto i changed my code as you said.But now also it is not working.Please help me

Comment: test.html page without anything else should show username in alert pop-up window. Do you get pop-up window or not? And if yes, is message is empty? Do you have blocked pop-up windows? Check for the small icon in the address bar.

Comment: Yes,the popup window is showing.But alert doesn't work.the window asks for username and password.But when i tried to alert,it doesn't work